# raspivid h264 output can't be played by Firefox video player

Tags: raspivid

If I record a video with `raspivid`, the output doesn't seem to be a perfectly valid video file. I can play it with `mplayer`, but Firefox's `<video>` tag can't play (although it's supposed to support h264).
If I run a `ffmpeg -i out.h264 out.mp4`, the output file can be played by Firefox.

According to `mediainfo`, this is the difference between the two files:

```
General
Complete name                            : out.h264
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
File size                                : 230 MiB

Video
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=60
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
```

```
General
Complete name                            : out.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 36.1 MiB
Duration                                 : 48s 0ms
Overall bit rate                         : 6 303 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Tagged date                              : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Writing application                      : Lavf56.40.101

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 48s 0ms
Bit rate                                 : 6 302 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.122
Stream size                              : 36.1 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 140
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Encoded date                             : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Tagged date                              : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
```

It seems to me that some kind of header information is missing. Does anybody know an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're encountering is the difference between the H.264 compression format, and the MP4 [container format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_container_format). Per [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats#Video_formats_supported), linked from [Mozilla's own support pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/H.264_support_in_Firefox), Firefox supports MP4, but not H.264 without a container.

The easiest eay to fix it is to encode everything as an MP4 (or another suitable container format). The information attached in the container is non-trivial, and not available in the raw H.264 file.

[This page](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/05/capturing-hd-video-with-the-pi-camera-module/) at [raspberrypi-spy.co.uk](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk) outlines a couple of options for putting raspivid's H.264 output in an MP4 container:

[MP4Box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y gpac
MP4Box -fps 30 -add myvid.h264 myvid.mp4
```

[avconv](https://libav.org/avconv.html):

```
sudo apt-get install -y libav-tools
avconv -r 30 -i myvid.h264 -vcodec copy myvid.mp4
```

Comment: There's no way to directly output MP4 with `raspivid`, right?

Comment: You know, I'd thought there was but apparently there isn't. I'll add a wee kibble to the answer.

Comment: I think raspivid will output `mjpeg` which [according to this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG#M-JPEG_over_HTTP) firefox supports.  It's the most portable format I've found for use with the pi cam without an intermediate conversion in userland like `avconv` (don't bother if you want streaming) but it might as well be uncompressed, the data rate is so obscene (8-10 MB/s at full resolution and framerate).  `uv4l` will definitely output this.